# How can I cross-reference a database table by itself?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've been trying to find a way (armed with only a basic knowledge of php and a wildly optimistic sense of determination) to search a wordpress database for meta-values based on other meta-values.

I need to get an item name from one table (wp_posts) using the post's ID, use it to obtain the post_id of items with the same name in another table (wp_postmeta) and then get from the same table the values for a particular custom field for every post_id obtained.

Since I'm new to this I attempted to do it by breaking it down into parts and here's what I've got.

```
<!--  This part works and gets the post title as expected -->

    <?php
        $result1 =$wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_title FROM $wpdb->posts , $wpdb->postmeta where  $wpdb->posts.ID = $post->ID", OBJECT);

        print_r($result1[0]->post_title);
    ?>

<!-- Then, I expected this to return the post_id of all entries where the title is the same as the one just obtained and where meta_key = custom_field_one. But it doesn't -->

    <?php
        $result2 =$wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->posts , $wpdb->postmeta where  $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = $result1 AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = custom_field_one", OBJECT );

        print_r($result2->post_id);
    ?>

<!-- So, unsurprisingly, this part doesn't work either. But it should use every post_id it just obtained to once again search the postmeta table -->

    <?php
        $result3 =$wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->posts , $wpdb->postmeta where  $wpdb->postmeta.post_id = $result2 AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = custom_field_two", OBJECT );

        print_r($result3->meta_value);
    ?>
```

Since the first query works, and the subsequent ones are just slight variations on that I expected it all to work. But, well, I was wrong.

Incidentally, I've tried a number of syntax variations in case that was an issue and I'm aware there are some issues regarding arrays.  So any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't figure ut your schema from your question, but you should be able to do that in one query using the postId similar to what @mikeb suggested.

Comment: Look closely at  `https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb`   @mikeb is correct, best way to do a 'three pronged search' is to NOT perform three searchs.  It will work, but you will get stuck in your underwear trying to get the formats to line up.  Let SQL work for you.  Do one (and only one) query for exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: One more thought.  This question really should have been asked over at `http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/`  Have you checked that site for similar / related questions?  A lot of folks there are top notch at using the wordpress database 'classes'.

Comment: No, I didn't know there was a Wordpress specific part of SO. But I'll see how far I get on my own following @mikeb's advice and head over there if I get stuck again. Thanks for the suggestions everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aliases:

```
SELECT 
    a1.Name, 
    b1.Info
FROM table2 b1
JOIN table2 a1 ON b1.id= a1.id AND a1.status = 1
```